# Handle errors in react native and redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a react native application using redux for state management.
On every API request, I have actions dispatched which is handled by reducer. This is then forwarded to saga and back to reducer.

I am using snackbar to show any errors which might have happened.

e.g. In the login flow, one of the operations is to fetch the OTP for username.

The action types are:

- GET_OTP_FOR_USER_REQUEST
- GET_OTP_FOR_USER_SUCCESS
- GET_OTP_FOR_USER_FAILURE

The initial state for the reducer (LoginReducer) is

```
{
    hasError: false,
    error : {
       display_message : "",
       details : null
    }
    otherData : []
}
```

Now in case of GET_OTP_FOR_USER_FAILURE, the reducer will be updated to

```
{
    hasError: true,
    error : {
       display_message : "Invalid Username",
       details : null
    }
    otherData : []
}
```

In my view component, I conditionally render the snackbar based on the hasError flag

```
{this.props.hasError ? Snackbar.show({
                title: this.props.error.display_message,
                duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
            }) : null}
```

**If I don't reset the hasError, then the snackbar keeps coming for every setState call (which happens on textinputchange).**

The current approach I am using is, I have an action to RESET_ERROR. 
I call this action once the setState is called on the textbox on the component (in this case the username)

```
onUserNameTextChanged = (text) => {

    this.props.resetError(); //Reset the error

    this.setState({ //something });

}
```

The issue with this is that this.props.resetError(); will get called on every character update. 
Just to ensure that I don't call render multiple time, I am using shouldComponentUpdate

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(this.props.hasError && (this.props.hasError === nextProps.hasError))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

I am not sure if there is simpler or cleaner approach to handle these scenarios. Any directions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can just conditionally call it if there's an error, that way you're not always invoking it:

```
onUserNameTextChanged = (text) => {
    if (this.props.hasError) {
        this.props.resetError(); //Reset the error
    }

    this.setState({ //something });

}
```

You can also tie it into the success action if you want that error to show until the API returns successfully.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's definitely lot simpler than managing it on life-cycle events.